# How to traverse thought string separated by ':' using python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

- I have string s="1:a:2,2:b:4,3:c:4,4:d:1"
- `1:a:2` first one is employ id, second one is person name, third one is Manger id
- My output is

```
a is report to b
b is report to d
c is report to d
d is report to a
```

```py
l = []
for each in s.split(','):
    for each_ite in each:
        l.append(each_ite)
for each in l:
    #find the first element
    #traverse to 3rd element
```

Comment: The code shown does not produce that output. Maybe you posted the wrong code. Also, try to be clear about what your output should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By means of mapping of `{emp_id: (emp_name, man_id) ...}`:

```
s = "1:a:2,2:b:4,3:c:4,4:d:1"
d = dict([((data := el.split(':'))[0], data[1:]) for el in s.split(',')])
for e_id, (e_name, m_id) in d.items():
    print(f"{e_name} is reported to {d[m_id][0]}")
```

---

```
a is reported to b
b is reported to d
c is reported to d
d is reported to a
```

Comment: A dictionary comprehension and using a separate `for` level to bind the name `data` would likely be more readable.

Comment: what is `(data := ` called, is it in the latest python only ??

Comment: @MakHus https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a list of dictionaries from your data. Your main issue is in not splitting each entry on `:`.

```py
s = "1:a:2,2:b:4,3:c:4,4:d:1"
data = [
  {'emp_id': info[0], 'name': info[1], 'mgr_id': info[2]}
  for line in s.split(',')
  # splitting the line on ':' into a list of substrings
  # and storing in a tuple of one element lets us essentially
  # assign the name 'info` to this list and use it in creating 
  # the dictionary.
  for info in (line.split(':'),)
]

# [{'emp_id': '1', 'name': 'a', 'mgr_id': '2'}, 
#  {'emp_id': '2', 'name': 'b', 'mgr_id': '4'}, 
#  {'emp_id': '3', 'name': 'c', 'mgr_id': '4'}, 
#  {'emp_id': '4', 'name': 'd', 'mgr_id': '1'}]
```

Now we can iterate through finding the name of the manager. We'll use `next` and supply a generator expression that checks for a matching manager ID.

```
>>> for entry in data:
...   mgr_id = entry['mgr_id']
...   mgr = next(e for e in data if e['emp_id'] == mgr_id)
...   print(f"{entry['name']} reports to {mgr['name']}")
...
a reports to b
b reports to d
c reports to d
d reports to a
```

Comment: Which is fine for little data, but instead of linear search might be better a dictionary to get the name from the employee's id.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score -2):

```
for each in s.split(","):
  employ_id, name, manager_id = each.split(":")
  # do whatever with them
```

What this does is it creates the list with all of the parts of the string split on commas, which I compressed into a list comprehension for speed reasons, then it will loop over each item, split it on the colon, and assigns variables `employ_id`, `name`, and `manager_id` to the values, which you can then do something with inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Your list comprehension does not work.

Comment: @Chris How does it not work? If it's because `s` isn't a variable, I left that out so you can add your own.

Comment: Did you run this code? I get an immediate error: `NameError: name 'each' is not defined`

Comment: @Chris Whoops, the `for`s are in the wrong order, I'll fix that!

Comment: Now `l` is `['1', ':', 'a', ':', '2', '2', ':', 'b', ':', '4', '3', ':', 'c', ':', '4', '4', ':', 'd', ':', '1']`.  You may want to rethink this.

Comment: @Chris Ok, its fixed now. I copied the original code, without realizing that that is getting all characters, instead of the groups.

Comment: One last comment: `l = [each for each in s.split(",")]` is just a longer way to write `l = s.split(",")`